# How do I add a custom view to stack layout from code behind in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Forms component that has a StackLayout in the Xaml. I've given it a xName of stackView.

I have another custom custom component that I would like to add to the stack layout programmatically from code behind but I'm getting and error and I'm not sure why.

The error I get says that my custom login view can't be converted to Xamarin.Forms.View

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TechPact
{
    public partial class CustomView : ContentPage
    {
        public CustomView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stackView.Children.Add(new CustomLoginView());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Login view

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TechPact.CustomLoginView">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Login with Facebook" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

here is the code behind for the login view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TechPact
{
    public partial class CustomLoginView : ContentPage
    {
        public TechPactLoginView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Derive you CustomLoginView from ContentView not Page

Answer (score 1):

Does your CustomLoginView extend ContentView or another Xamarin Forms View?
The code you posted should work if it does

Comment: It extends ContentPage

Comment: Your component should extend ContentView, not ContentPage.
You can also extend Layouts like StackLayout or AbsoluteLayout, or even other Views, like DatePicker, the one thing you can't do is extend ContentPage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it was a bug with Xamarin Studio or if changing Login View to extend ContnetView rather than ContentPage, but it is working now after I did that.

Comment: look at my answer :-)